# yepnope.js resource fallbacks not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, yepnope

I used the code straight from the examples on yepnope's homepage:

```
  yepnope([{
    load: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js',
    complete: function() {
      console.log('made it');
      if(!window.jQuery) { yepnope('/js/jquery.1.5.2-min.js'); }
    }
  }]);
```

I've been working without internet today and I noticed that my local version of jQuery is not being loaded.

Since I'm not connected to the internet I would assume in the example above the Google CDN version would fail to load, the `complete` function would be called which would load my local copy.  It looks like `complete` is not being called at all because I am not seeing 'made it' in the console.

Also, I checked and the path to my local copy is correct.

Comment: Maybe they changed it since this question, but the example currently on the homepage uses the callback event, and not the complete event as you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT based on your comments and question update:**

You have to wait for it to time out.  The complete function won't fire immediately.  I just downloaded yepnope.js and ran their demo/index.html with the following code added just under their yepnope call that loads jQuery at the bottom of the page:

```
yepnope({

  load     : "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js",
  callback : function() { console.log("callback"); },
  complete : function() { console.log("complete"); }

});
```

Obviously jQuery 1.6.2 will not load.  About 10-15 seconds later in the console, both the "callback" and "complete" messages show up, so I know they are getting fired.

**Alernative:**

If you find that you are only needing this functionality for developing online/offline, you might try what [Html5Boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com) uses, which I have adpoted:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; 
     fall back to local if necessary -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js">\x3C/script>')
</script>
```

**Here's what I personally use:**

```
    </form>

    <!-- Javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->

    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery UI, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $.ui || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <!-- Scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
    <script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End scripts -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually do have that in my code, sorry I just didn't copy it over correctly.  I will update my question.

Comment: I guess I could just load jQuery with script tags html5 boilerplate style and then use yepnope for the rest of my scripts.  I wonder if that will work or not, since all of my scripts depend upon jQuery.

Comment: I'll update my answer and show you what I do on my projects, and it's the best practice shown in Html5Boilerplate by Paul Irish.  I don't even use yepnope.js for loading scripts.  You shouldn't ever need to load but 3 or 4 tops if you use Modernizr in your head, which includes yepnope and html5 shim for IE.

Comment: @Scott your comment isn't quite true. One of the benefits of yepnope is to allow for parallelization of downloads. Your 4 `<script>` tags will only ever load *sequentially*. This could produce additional delays in your page load time for first time visitors (visitors with an empty cache). So this isn't necessarily the best answer particularly if you have a sizable amount of jQuery plugins or site scripts in which case an asynchronous script loader could significantly improve load times.